# grep - search for "<?\n" at start of a file

Tags: regex, ack, grep

I have a hunch that I should probably be using ack or egrep instead, but what should I use to basically look for

```
<?
```

at the start of a file? I'm trying to find all files that contain the php short open tag since I migrated a bunch of legacy scripts to a relatively new server with the latest php 5.

I know the regex would probably be `'/^<\?\n/'`

Comment: I think you've answered your own question

Comment: are you just looking to find all php short tags?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't, I'm pretty sure that there was some argument I was supposed to pass for grep to do *full* PCRE compatible, I think it just has basic support by default.

Comment: @smotchkiss - pretty much heh.. migrated some old code to a new server and I don't want to enable short tags.

Comment: i think php will need \n to be in double quotes if it is to be interpreted as a newline character, so your regex would be "/^<\?\n/"

Comment: thanks all. edited the description so there are more keywords for what I was actually trying to achieve.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I RTFM and ended up using:

```
grep -RlIP '^<\?\n' *
```

the P argument enabled full perl compatible regexes.

Comment: mark this question as answered so we can get on with our lives ;)

Comment: But in the meantime, you can get a Self-Learner badge for actually RTFM. *clicks +1* :-P

Answer (score 4):

If you're looking for all php short tags, use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

```
/<\?(?!php)/
```

will match `<?` but will not match `<?php`

```
[meder ~/project]$ grep -rP '<\?(?!php)' .
```

Comment: +1 for thinking of negative lookaheads and specifying -P too.

Answer (score 2):

```
find . -name "*.php" | xargs  grep -nHo "<?[^p^x]"
```

^x to exclude xml start tag

Comment: Works nicely and doesn't require grep to be recompiled with Perl regex support

Answer (score 1):

if you worried about windows line endings, just add `\r?`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grep '^<?$' filename
```

Don't know if that is showing up correctly. Should be

grep ' ^ < ? $ ' filename

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean a literal "backslash n" or do you mean a newline?

For the former:

```
grep '^<?\\n' [files]
```

For the latter:

```
grep '^<?$' [files]
```

Note that grep will search all lines, so if you want to find matches just at the beginning of the file, you'll need to either filter each file down to its first line, or ask grep to print out line numbers and then only look for line-1 matches.